# Conditional Logic On A Link

Tags: javascript, wordpress

How can I have a link go to a page as expected for logged in users only?  If a user is not logged in I would like a popup login form displayed instead.

PS-I am new to JS and StackOverflow so please be kind and if my future questions should be set up differently, please let me know.

I have tried a lot of different methods and I am able to get the script to display alerts, but not the desired actions.

This is the link HTML that should go to the defined href value if user is logged in and display the pop up if logged out.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="lockedContent()" id="bookOne">Go To New Page</a>
```

Here is the script I am using and could use help with actions that need to happen.

```
<script>
  function lockedContent(){
    if (document.body.classList.contains("logged-in")){
      //go to link defined in the href in the <a>
    } else {
      //display login popup
    }
  }
</script>
```

I would like the link to go to the desired `url` in the `href` for logged in users and to display a popup for users that are not logged in.  So far I can't seem to get either to happen.

Comment: Client-side authorization is a dangerous game. Leave the redirecting to your server.

Comment: Adam, thank you for your note.  I am not sure if I am following though.  Sorry, total rookie here.

Comment: Any authorization run on the client side can easily be manipulated by a user.

Comment: Def listen to Adam

Comment: Ok, so what method do you suggest for a solution to this scenario?

Comment: Hey @lisrael, sorry i missed this. What you want to search, there are several plugins and approaches, is `wordpress require login for certain pages` drop that into google and you should find your answer.

Comment: Adam, thank you. I do plan to have this be the case on pages that require users to be logged in.  Page would open if user logged in and redirect back to home page if not logged in or static login page.  However, I am trying to apply this logic to the link that is in the say the search results.  So before the page would load the logic would apply.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense and is exactly how it _should_ work. I'm not exactly sure how the redirecting back to the search results after login would work however I'm sure there are plugins that would take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect using `window.location`. After proper authorization you can add the class `logged-in` to the body and then redirect

```
if (document.body.classList.contains("logged-in")) {
  // only after proper authorization 
  window.location.href = 'url of the page'
} else {
  // code to call modal display function
}
```

Comment: brk, thank you for your answer, this makes sense to me.  However, is there a way to reference the URL that is in the link, versus hard coding the URL?  I would like to have multiple links on a single page set up with this script, but each goes to a different page.

Comment: thats possible.

Comment: I am glad that's possible.  Do you think you can tell me how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button instead and check if user is logged in or not based on that change [**window.location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```js
let loggedIn = true
function lockedContent(){
  if(loggedIn)
  {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
    console.log(window.location.href)
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="lockedContent()" id="bookOne">Go To New Page</button>
```

Comment: Code Maniac, thank you for your answer as well.  I need to keep the link as text vs a button to match other links and content on the page.  Can you also help me understand why you added the console.log line?

Comment: console line is just to show the change happening, nothing else than that, you can use `span`